# Data Validation for Records

Tags: json, haskell, record, aeson, lenses

Are you aware of any Haskell library that

1. provides some simplification for record **validation** and (!)
2. works with **Aeson**?

I know that I could write some constructor functions but I would like to erase the boilerplate without reinventing the wheel.

What I am looking for is the following:

I would like to define "contracts" for each field. For instance:

```
data Person = Person {
     age   :: Integer
    ,email :: Text
    ,projects :: [Project]}
```

Now, I would like to guarantee that after I parse the JSON into the record, the following holds:

1. age in [0,Inf)
2. email matches "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,6}$"
3. project contains at least 2 projects

If I try to create a record with an age < 0, I will get an error message like "age=0 no in [0,inf)". I assume something like this should be possible to be derived via template Haskell.

Furthermore, I would like to integrate this into the parser phase. Hence, instead of getting an error message like "when expected an Integral, encountered String instead", I would like to get an error message that

1. Shows the position of the error (not sure if this is possible with attoparsec)
2. Describes the error.

Comment: See "smart constructors"

Comment: @luqui: Thx - had this in mind as well but I haven't found an easy way to integrate smart constructors into Aeson - plus, I'm not sure how to combine this with lenses.

Comment: Seems like making the constructor return a Monad helps - still leaves the problem that Aeson doesn't report where the error occurred. Thanks, luqui, for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ocharles has created exactly such a package! http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors-aeson